# MS Access requery form after group delete

Tags: ms-access-2010

Access 2010 & Access backend.

1. I use a Delete query to delete a select group of items on a
   continuous form.
2. The Delete query is in the form_delete event and
   it works.
3. in the form_AfterDelConfirm event I have a me.requery command but the form is not requeried because in the form_delete I have Cancel = True which prevents the AfterDelConfirm event from firing.  If i change the Cancel to False the AfterDelConfirm fires but the me.requery produces an error that the record is in use by another user (I am the only user).

The problem is that the continuous form displays #Deleted
    in the deleted records of the deleted group items.

I also have a requery button that requeries the subform which clears the deleted items.

My goal is to have the deleted items clear without the user having to click the requery button.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Skip the delete query. Instead, delete directly from the form using its recordset in the code you call from the button click:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone

While Not rs.EOF
    ' Specify conditions for a delete, for example:
    If rs!FieldA.Value = SomeNumber And rs!FieldB.Value = "SomeText" Then
        rs.Delete
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Wend

Set rs = Nothing
```

No requery of the form will be needed.

Comment: I used your method and the records were removed from the form but not from the table.  I opened and closed the table a number of times to check but the records were still there and one had the focus preventing further manipulation.

Comment: That I cannot replicate. Even if the form's _AllowDelete_ is set to True, the records will be deleted, and if the form's recordsource is read-only, `rs.Delete` will fail. So something else is going on.

Comment: Something is weird but I accept your solution as being correct.  The recordsource cannot be read-only because if I use my delete query and then requery the records are deleted.  I have decided to let the user click the requery button for now so thanks for the help.